# CodeIgniter no database selected

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on this, using a CRUD tutorial:

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }

    if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}
```

But I got this error message:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1046

No database selected

SELECT * FROM (`pages`) WHERE `slug` = 'about' ORDER BY `order`

Filename: /var/application/core/MY_Model.php

Line Number: 34($this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();)
```

How can I choose a database?

Comment: It seems that the database "pages" wasn't found. Check if that the correct name and that your config settings are defined correctly at application/config/database.

Comment: @Lior actually `pages` is the table...

Comment: yes pages is the table name how can i { SELECT * FROM (`pages`) WHERE `slug` = 'about' ORDER BY `order`} these query to work, thanks

Comment: Did you set your database info in application/config/database? Are you working with a live database or on a local server?

Comment: im working on local server and i have set database.php properly

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill out your database details in `/application/config/database.php`

Also, if you are using environments you may need to edit the `/application/config/{ENVIRONMENT}/database.php` file.

Comment: $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';

Comment: im using environment and i set it correctly(i think) but these crud is not working

Comment: Try `die('<pre>'.print_r($this->db, true).'</pre>');` somewhere, check what the values are in the `username`, `password`, `hostname` abd `database` keys.

Comment: If you are using environments check if you have a `/application/config/{ENVIRONMENT}/database.php` file, if so check the values in there, to find out what your active environment is just do `die(ENVIRONMENT)` (note we are dumping the environment constant)

Comment: i did and the value for these key return empty

Comment: THE ENVIRONMENT as well working it's development and database.php is also all correct!

Comment: Are you autoloading the database?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29458/discussion-between-hailwood-and-mercy)